# Property ‘createUser’ does not exist on type ‘AngularFireAuth’

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement authentication system using firebase but shows error when new user is creating account.

> Property ‘createUser’ does not exist on type ‘AngularFireAuth’

Code is:

```
export class SignupComponent {
    state: string = '';
    error: any;
    constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,private router: Router) { }
    onSubmit(formData) {
        if(formData.valid) {
        console.log(formData.value);
        this.afAuth.createUser({
            email: formData.value.email,
            password: formData.value.password
        }).then((success) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/members'])
        }).catch((err) => {this.error = err;})
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it state that this library has a `createUser` method?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: Where have you seen this usage `this.afAuth.createUser` ? In documentation?

Comment: I was learning authentication on youtube and in that tutorial it was used and i simply copied the code.https://coursetro.com/posts/code/32/Create-a-Full-Angular-Authentication-System-with-Firebase

Comment: I see a `this.af.auth.createUser`. Can you try, `this.afAuth.auth.createUser` ? Or maybe that's deprecated, have you tried also this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword?

Comment: `this.afAuth.auth.createUser` gives error `Property 'createUser' does not exist on type 'Auth'`

Comment: this.af.auth is likely referring to V3 of AngularFire2 V4 heavily refactored.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md), "AngularFireAuth.auth returns an initialized firebase.auth.Auth instance, allowing you to log users in, out, etc."  They offer a code example which includes this line:

`this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());`

The Angularfire docs go on to say "see the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) for more information on what methods are available."  Looking at those docs, it appears there is no longer a createUser method.  There is, however, one called `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.

So, try using `this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.